# How do I define only scheduler attributes in the deployment descriptor, not the whole bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have the following bean:

```
@Stateless
public class NewSessionBean {

    public void myJob() {
        System.out.println("RUN");
    }
}
```

and I would like to have myJob running every 10 seconds, so I have this Deployment descriptor:

```
<ejb-jar xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  version = "3.1"
  xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>NewSessionBean</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>org.test.NewSessionBean</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <timer>
        <schedule>
          <second>*/10</second>
          <minute>*</minute>
          <hour>*</hour>
          <month>*</month>
          <year>*</year>
        </schedule>
        <timeout-method>
          <method-name>myJob</method-name>
       </timeout-method>
     </timer>
   </session>
 </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

And it works.

But I would like to declare only the timer in my deployment descriptor, not the whole bean so I can declare everything using annotations and parametrize the schedule.

If I remove the ejb-class or session-type my application won't load because the DD is missing this information.

Is there anyway that I can override the information for the scheduler only?

Edit: I would like to move set the parameters on the @schedule annotation to the deployment descriptor so I can change its values without needing to recompile/redeploy anything.

Comment: The EJB spec isn't really set up well to mix and match annotations with the XML descriptors. People usually use one or the other. Can you explain why you don't want to use the [`@Schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) annotation?

Comment: @dcsohl thanks for the comment  :) I am new at the JavaEE world, and I thought that one great feature of the deployment descriptor would be the capacity of overriding the annotations, enabling changes without the need of redeploys. I would like to use the DD in order to be able to change the values of the scheduler (minute, hour, etc) without needing to recompile the code

Comment: Your example should work as-is per the spec, and I know it works on WebSphere Application Server.  What application server are you using?

Comment: Yes,it works. But I  would like to remove the definition of the bean and define only the scheduler in the dd